# jsfiddle question

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, document-ready, nowrap

I can't get this extremely simple jsfiddle to work. Its just supposed to alert test when button is clicked. What am I missing here?

http://jsfiddle.net/u9nG6/2/

Comment: Simple remark: Instead of bind `click`, you've better to trap `submit` event!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to change the load method to no wrap (head).

It has something to do with how the JavaScript gets loaded and when the method signature is read. http://jsfiddle.net/u9nG6/11/

Comment: To be specific: the `onDomReady` wraps the function and it only exists in that scope. The `no wrap` means that the function exists in the global scope.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery framework is selected to load `onDomReady` so your function is wrapped in the jQuery anonymous function `$(function(){ });` and is not visible. Either change jQuery to load as `no wrap (head)` or define your function at the global scope.

Answer (score 2):

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u9nG6/16/).

You needed to define your `validateForm` function at the global scope in order to be able to use it in the HTML like that. Otherwise you had it defined as a function *within* the scope of the `onDomReady` event, which is inaccessible outside that scope.

A more "jQuery-ish" approach would be to use jQuery to handle the `click` event like this:

```
$("#id_btnSubmit").click(validateForm);
```

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/u9nG6/18/) for an example of that suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You're using jquery + ondomready. This means any javascript you write is placed within

```
$(function() {
```

and

```
});
```

this leads to a scope problem. You can try the following instead.

```
window.validateForm = function() {
}
```