# jsfiddle click code not responding

Tags: jsfiddle

I can't get this fiddle to work

https://jsfiddle.net/mtgna/rwhu14ot/

```
enter code here
```

I have tried changing the javascript load method to no wrap(Head) as per
[jsfiddle question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823587/jsfiddle-question)
but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?
    `<button class="myButton" onclick="sniffles.talk()">`

This line doesn't seem to do what you want it to do. 
$('button.myButton').click(sniffles.talk())